# Video/image capture software for USB camera on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, camera

I recently purchased a generic USB endoscope camera from a Chinese distributor.  It didn't come with any drivers or software, but it is recognized by Windows 7:

[image: DeviceManager]

And it can be used by Skype:

[image: Skype]

---

I'm looking for software that can capture pictures and video from this camera. I've found any number of freeware programs online but there's no way for me to tell if they are legit or simply vectors for ad/spam/malware.

I'm not too picky about the software functionality. I would like software (or even a Windows utility) that's:

- Free, although cheap is almost as good :)
- Established enough that I don't have to worry about malware...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC can do all of that, and more

https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-record-your-webcam-with-vlc/

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  That's just the kind of thing I was looking for.